# How to fetch data of last month from database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where records for a user are stored

This includes 2 columns `applied_date.`,`js_id.`

now i have to count js_id have applied  to number of job this month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select count(js_id) from yourtable   WHERE DATEDIFF( m, applied_date, GETDATE() ) = 0
```

Comment: If i want to  `count js_id  of today applied ` like using `DATEDIFF( m, applied_date, GETDATE() ) `then what should change in query.`Select count(js_id) from yourtable   WHERE DATEDIFF( m, applied_date, GETDATE() ) = 0`

Comment: you should change the first parameter, from m to d ) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(js_id), MONTH(applied_date)
FROM table
GROUP BY MONTH(applied_date)
```

Comment: This won't take the year into account, so I suspect it's not what the OP wants

Comment: Also it is unlikely to use any indexes on the `applied_date` column, if they exist.

Comment: @AdaTheDev My bad, indeed it only looks at the month and not the year

Answer (score 2):

For a specific month (given a date),

```
DECLARE @date SMALLDATETIME = '20120105'; -- for January, also could use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
-- the above could also be a stored procedure parameter

SET @date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date), 0);

SELECT COUNT(js_id) 
  FROM dbo.[table_name]
  WHERE applied_date >= @date
  AND applied_date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date);
```